# flatening a list based on priority

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, loops, flatten

I have a list of contracts that has a timespan to be finished in. some contracts are more important than others. if there is an overlap between two contracts we cut down the less important one in a way that will either cut in two, cut it from the start or the end or fully remove it.

my problem is: I've implemented the algorithm but I still have some minor errors which cause a false output. I think the error comes from the if case where the less important contract will get cut in two and get added to the result list but the result list already has the uncut version which needed to be somehow removed so we don't have 3 contract but just 2 cut contracts and the contract from which these 2 cut contracts came need to be removed

this is my new updated code

```
List<Contract> resultContracts = new List<Contract>()
{
    contractList[0]
};
int n = contractList.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < contractList.Count; i++)
{

    var lastProcessedContract = contractList[i]; // high priority
    var contractsToRemove = new List<Contract>();

    for (var j = i + 1;  j < contractList.Count; j++){

        var lessPriorityContract = contractList[j];

        if (lessPriorityContract.start >= lastProcessedContract.start && lessPriorityContract.end <= lastProcessedContract.end)
        /*
         *  ------------------------>
         *           ------>
         * oder
         *  ------------------------>
         *  -------->
         *  oder
         *  ------------------------->
         *                    ------->
         *
         * oder
         * --------------------------->
         * --------------------------->
         */
        {
            contractsToRemove.Add(lessPriorityContract);
        }
        else if ((lessPriorityContract.start < lastProcessedContract.start 
                 && (lessPriorityContract.end > lastProcessedContract.start && lessPriorityContract.end <= lastProcessedContract.end)) || 
                 ((lastProcessedContract.start < lessPriorityContract.end && lastProcessedContract.start > lessPriorityContract.start)
                     && lastProcessedContract.end > lessPriorityContract.end))
       /* 
          *     ------------------------>
          *  ------>
          * oder
          *     ------------------------------->
          * ----------------------------------->
          


        // oder 
        


          *                   -------------->
          *  ------------------------>
        
        */

        {
            lessPriorityContract.end = lastProcessedContract.start.AddDays(-1);
            resultContracts.Add(lessPriorityContract);
        }
        else if (((lessPriorityContract.start < lastProcessedContract.end && lessPriorityContract.start >= lastProcessedContract.start)
                 && lessPriorityContract.end > lastProcessedContract.end) || (lastProcessedContract.start < lessPriorityContract.start &&
                                                                              (lastProcessedContract.end > lessPriorityContract.start && lastProcessedContract.end < lessPriorityContract.end)))
        /*
         * -------------------->
         *            ------------------------->
         *
         * oder
         * -------------------->
         * ---------------------------------->
         *
         


        //oder
        


          *  ------------>
          *       ------------------->
          * 
         */ 
        {
            lessPriorityContract.start = lastProcessedContract.end.AddDays(1);
            resultContracts.Add(lessPriorityContract);
        }
        else if(lessPriorityContract.start < lastProcessedContract.start
                && lessPriorityContract.end > lastProcessedContract.end)
            /*
             *       ------------>
             * --------------------------->
             * oder
             * --------------------------->
             * --------------------------->
             * 
             */
        {

            var contract = new Contract
            {
                start = lessPriorityContract.start,
                end = lastProcessedContract.start.AddDays(-1),
                priority = lessPriorityContract.priority,
                price = lessPriorityContract.price
            };
            //contractList.Remove(contractList[i]);
            //contractList.Add(contract);
            resultContracts.Add(contract);
            contract = new Contract
            {
                start = lastProcessedContract.end.AddDays(1),
                end = lessPriorityContract.end,
                priority = lessPriorityContract.priority,
                price = lessPriorityContract.price
            };
            resultContracts.Add(contract);
            //contractList.Add(contract);
        }
    }
    foreach (var contractToRemove in contractsToRemove)
    {
        contractList.Remove(contractToRemove);
    }

}

resultContracts.Sort(new ContractComparer());

foreach (var flatElement in resultContracts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(flatElement.ToString());
}
```

I am open to get new efficient and faster algorithms too, otherwise reparing of this would be also immensly helpful. thank you!

the class contractor(datetime start, datetime end, double price, int priority) and it has a method which sort based on priority. the class ContractComparer sort based on the start date

Comment: Please provide relevant code such as `Contract`, `ContractComparer`, and an explanation of what ”shrink“ and "override" means.

Comment: Contract is just a class with 4 attribute :start and end(DateTime), price(double)and priority (int). Contractcomparer) helps me sort based on the attribut start and I have a method in the contract class which   sort based on priority. At the beginning I soet the list based on priority and I ser the first element(highest priority) in the list because it is not going to be override  whatsoever

Comment: By override I mean the fact that the start or the end of the low priority contract will be cut down because some other high prioritized contract is to be executed

Comment: Sometimes there is cases where the whole contract can be overriden when the whole contract is in the time of another important one

Comment: Shrink is cutting the contract small

Comment: There is cases where a low priority contract can be split into too. That means after finishing the important contract we can keep on working on the one that we stopped

Comment: Mouad, when asked for clarification it's generally best to edit your question rather than to answer in a comment. If a reader doesn't understand something about your question it's a good bet that other readers will have the same problem. We cannot expect readers to read all the comments. Questions therefore need to be self-contained. Also it may be helpful to include an example to help clarify what you are saying in the first paragraph.

Comment: thank you. I don't usually use stackoverflow a lot that's why I didn't notice.  I 've made some changes :)

Comment: Mouad, if you wish to direct a comment to a particular member include their username prefixed with a `'@'` (e.g., `@CarySwoveland`). SO will then notify that member that a comment has been left for them. I didn't need to do that with my comment to you because authors of questions are notified of all comments left on their question. The same holds for answers.

Comment: What happens if 2 contracts have the same priority and overlapped time?

Answer (score 0):

> My errors are caused by the change of the length of my list within the loops which is something to be avoided but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to understand your code *as is* but based on what I did understand you seem to have identified your problem already.

Create an `int` outside of your loops and assign `contractList.Count` to it. This will give you the freedom of when to add or remove a value from your iterator without relying on `contractList.Add()` or `contractList.Remove()`

This likely isn't the best solution but it might be enough to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are processing time ranges with priority, and not just objects with a timespan. I would propose the following

1. Sort contracts by priority
2. For each contract:

   1. Check if each contract overlaps with any existing contract in the result list. If the number of contracts is reasonably small, an exhaustive search will do. If there are a huge number you might want some search structure, see [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).
   2. If there is overlap, use whatever conflict resolution you want, like rejecting the contract, changing the start time, or removing any overlapping ranges. Note that the later may result in multiple time ranges, i.e. a long low priority contract being split in half by a short high priority contract.
   3. Add any results to the result lists

This should ensure that the highest priority contracts gets first pick of time slots, since they are processed first.